# Can an Undead Servitor act after its controller is dead?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, actions, undead, minion

**Can an Undead Servitor act after it's controller is dead?**

EDIT: (Note that this is not 'act as a sentient creature capable of making it's own choices of action' but 'act' as in 'perform actions'.)

F. Randall Farmer pointed out a potential flaw in my cunning self-resurrection plan from the [Can an Undead Servitor use a Ritual Scroll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14903/can-an-undead-servitor-use-a-ritual-scroll) question.

> You imbue a humanoid corpse of natural origin and Medium or smaller
> size with the ability to move under its own power and an understanding
> of one language of your choice. It has speed 6 and Strength 16, never
> tires, and obeys you at all times. The undead servitor is a
> noncombatant. When forced onto an active battlefield, treat the
> servitor as an allied minion (1 hit point, never damaged on a missed
> attack) with all defenses of 11. **It acts just after you do and never
> makes attacks.** You cannot have more than one undead servitor at a time
> from different performances of this ritual. If you attempt to create a
> second servitor, that ritual fails without component expenditure.

The argument was that, as it acts after you do, if you can't act (due to being dead or unconscious) neither can it, even if you have given it orders to be triggered on your demise.

Is this correct?

EDIT - There is perhaps some confusion as to what I am getting at with this question, so here is a scenario to make it clear.

1. A wizard, just about to die, tells his servitor to carry his corpse
   to his pre-prepared tomb once he has expired.
2. He also tells it that once it has finished this, it must dust his tower to make it
   presentable.
3. Finally he tells it that when it has finished dusting (each surface once, no endless tasks here), it must obey any and all orders given to it by the wizard's heir.
4. The wizard then dies.

What happens?

FURTHER EDIT:

To break down the instructions:

1. Wait until my death, then do this.
2. When 1. completes, do this.
3. When 2. completes, accept further instructions.

If 1. is not performed, it means active commands are cancelled upon the death of the person who ordered them.
If 1. is performed, but 2. is not, then the servitor is capable of fulfilling a single command that applies after it's creator's death, but cannot have further instructions become active after this point.  This would be arbitrary.
If 1. and 2. are performed, but 3. is not, a servitor cannot obey an order to obey orders, which is nonsense.

Comment: Hmm, if you are unconscious then you do still have an initiative right? For example when making death saving throws you are unconscious, but do still have to roll a dice on your turn. So I think this is really only a valid question for if you are dead, as conscious/unconscious does not change when you have a 'turn'.

Comment: Good point - the question was as F. Randall Farmer phrased it, and I didn't consider that angle.  I'll update it.

Comment: I'd guess that the answer to this question will hinge entirely on how one interprets the words **acts**: does that mean taking a full set of Standard+Move+Minor actions, or does it purely mean 'this is his initiative'?

Comment: Yes - I had interpreted it as the latter.  The other point was whether that line only applied when considering it as an entity on the battlefield - the Unseen Servant has no such line, as it can't become a minion due to having no physical form.  It also says it 'obeys you at all times' - it seems odd to consider it'd stop sweeping the floor if you drop dead, even if it itself is permanent.

Comment: [Post clarification} Wow. That is a very complicated set of commands, including the legal inheritance.

Comment: The commands are a simple 'Do this.  Then do this.  Then accept further instructions.'

Comment: -1 "a servitor cannot obey an order to obey orders, which is nonsense" is snarky and cuts off discussion. Presupposing an answer to your question and prejudging any contrary position isn't a great way to get help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question.  It wasn't actually something I was wanting to ask anyway, the commentary on your own reply confirms the answer, and it was too unclear in it's wording for it to be obvious what I was actually asking.  I apologise for the snark, it was late when I wrote that.

Comment: Closing at asker's request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

I would read the line '**It acts just after you do**' as purely a matter of setting the Servitor's initiative score for encounters. With this interpretation there is then no reason to expect your character's death to affect the Servitor, beyond not being able to provide it with new commands.

Comment: What about setting up a Magic Mouth, to be triggered on your death?

Comment: It gets more tenous, as I'd argue that a Magic Mouth speaking your words with your voice is not 'you', and thus the Servitor will not obey it. This also prevents someone else from ordering your Servitor about by using recorded fragments of some words you said at some point. So you cannot give the Servitor new orders after your death, but you can possibly still tell it how to act (while you are still alive) once it finds out that you are dead. It would effectively be carrying out your last will and testament :D

Comment: What if what you had ordered in that eventuality was to follow the directions of the Magic Mouth? :P

Comment: Then it's fine!

Comment: It occurs to me a wizard with a computer-programming background could go a long way with if-then type orders.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

> *The corpse shudders, then clambers to its feet. At your direction, it shoulders your gear and lumbers after you.*[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=185)

An `Undead Servitor` is more of a pack mule than a henchman.

> You imbue a humanoid corpse of natural origin and Medium or smaller size with the ability to move under its own power and an understanding of one language of your choice.

This does ***not*** mean that the Undead Servitor has been resurrected (i.e. Druid `Restore Life`) in the usual game sense - it's called ***undead***, after all. The implication is that it has no will of it's own and is controlled entirely by its summoner. The restriction against attacking is telling - the Undead Servitor is incapable of action types that other summoned undead perform easily.

No summoner, no will. No will, no actions.

Just hire a henchman, it's less complicated and probably cheaper.

Comment: So it stops whatever it has been ordered to do if the summoner dies?  That seems at odds with 'obeys you at all times'.  Also, why then does it need to understand a language, if you have to devote your own will continously in order to get it to do things?

Comment: I didn't say either of those. It stops when it completes your last command. I also did not say anything about "continuous".

Comment: Wait, is it possible we actually agree? You say it stops once it completes the last command, I say it continues until there are no more commands (i.e. you're dead).

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer Wait, now I'm confused...you aren't saying that the servitor can't act after you are dead (the point of the question), but only that it can't decide on new actions for itself?

Comment: @ioanwigmore If we agree, why did you say "Yes" to the question? No commands = no actions. Right? Dead = No commands. So the answer to the question as phrase is "No". Clearly there is some difference that is escaping us all. :-)

Comment: The question was just updated with a complicated set of pre-death instructions. At this point the question has wandered away from a specific rule clarification to examining an individual edge-case. I'll let my answer stand as is, but I'm not going to get into a debate as the question shifts underneath us.

Comment: Well my "yes" meant it does not simply stop acting, it will still carrying out the last action asked of it. But yes this is getting tricky to answer...

Comment: @ All concerned: The question has never changed - all the original question was about whether the servitor could still perform actions to carry out orders if the person who created it was dead, as the original quibble was that it could have no actions if it acted after you. The 'complicated' instructions were a point of illustration.  I'll break them down into their implications...was meaning to do that last night.